# Resize Text In Cell iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iPhone application that fills the cell with text from some information from a server. How can I have that text auto-resize to fit? Right now it adds ... at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the properties `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and `minimumFontSize`, see the [UITextField reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888)

Comment: This worked. `cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = 10;`. I will accept your answer when it lets me. I don't know how I missed this (though to admit I was looking in the wrong section)

Comment: As per your information my textstring fits to label... I want to stretch my label as per my text string ! How can i ?

Comment: @NoOne I don't think you can do it automatically, but the NSString class has UIKit extensions in iOS, in particular you can use [`- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893) and resize it when needed.